# How can i use the GET method to send form data from one page to the next in a single JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My assignment requires me to, among others, use the GET method to submit form data from clientregistration.html to clientpayment.html. All JS code (code for a slideshow on the homepage, code to validate input data, etc.) has to be done in a single file. In the JS file, I have:

1. Specified the GET method and clientpayment.html as the form action
2. Used getElementByID for each input
3. used addEventListener for a click event to run custom validity functions for each field when the submit button is clicked

I need to, once the clientpayment.html file has loaded, use the queryString to display the formData in the page, above the next form. I can't figure out how to get the url of the page only when the clientpayment.html page has loaded. No server-side scripting is allowed.

I tried an Event Listener for the load event but to no avail. I would personally have a separate JS file just for the clientpayment.html page but the assignment requires we use a single file.

```
The code i would normally use in such an instance is:
// Get Customer Info from query string
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Retrieve the query string
    let qString = location.search.slice(1);

    // Replace encoded characters
    qString = qString.replace(/\+/g," ");
    qString = decodeURIComponent(qString);
    
    // Split the encoded characters into field-name pairs
    let clientData = qString.split(/&/g);
    
    for (let item of clientData) {
        let fieldValuePair = item.split(/=/g);
        let field = fieldValuePair[0];
        let value = fieldValuePair[1];
    
        localStorage.setItem(field, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) object it has functions for getting access to the different values in the query string. You use `window.location.search` as parameter. Here in SO it doesn't work, so in the example you can see that I create my own URL and parse the query string using URLSearchParams.

```js
console.log(window.location);
//var search = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

var url = new URL("https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2");
var search = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
console.log(search.get('foo'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the window.location.search method, I think I just phrased my question poorly. The script.js file will be linked to multiple html files so I need the window.location.search to execute only for clientpayment.html. I tried using an event listener for "load" but could not get that to work